# php insert into the database is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I am trying to insert some information into the database but it is not working. The following is my code:

```
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO favorites (posted-date,posted-time,posted-
datetime,journalid, by)  VALUES ('test','test','test','test','test')";
```

Comment: Not working how? Does it throw a query error? Can you show a structure of your database? And what do you use to query the db, mysqli?

Comment: If its not working then it might be throwing an error too. So post that error too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO `favorites` (`posted-date`,`posted-time`,`posted-datetime`,`journalid`, `by`) VALUES ('test','test','test','test','test')";
```

Also check if you are connecting to your database correctly.

And have a look at your table and all the fields if they are of correct type and exists.

Comment: can you please tell me what error exactly are you getting?

Comment: Before I could do an error check, it started working so I did not do an error check.

Comment: is your id set to auto-increment?

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. I still did not figure out the cause of the error, but the following is the working code:

$sql4 = "INSERT INTO  `favorites` (
`id` ,
`posted-date` ,
`posted-time` ,
`posted-datetime` ,
`journalid` ,
`by`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  'test',  'test',  'test',  'test',  'test'
)";

Comment: the solution worked because you used NULL value to insert for id.